# Spatial auto-correlation test for binary data in R

Tags: r, spatial, binary-data, spdep

I want to test a species' presence / absence records for spatial autocorrelation.  My data contain >130,000 grids in GIS and with about 700 species' presence records.

I have read that the normal Moran's $I$ can't deal with this kind of data, but that the join count method in package `spdep` can do it.  However, I'm new to `R` and I still can't understand the information and code in the help for `joincount.mc` or `joincount.test`.

My data is like this:

```
 gridnumber  species  
     1       1     
     2       0
     3       0
     4       1
     ……
```

I know how to read a `shp.file` into `R` and I know I must calculate the weight of my data, but the following steps with `spdep` is beyond my ability.

Comment: You might also want to explore the threads about `R` and `spdep` that have appeared at [gis.se].

Comment: @gung Thank you very much. Actually getting the code is most urgent to me, for I must perform the test for a analysis at hand. However, it may be the simplest solution for my current work but a better introduction for the statistic principle would be most appreciated. Now, I think it had better to migrate my question.  Thank you gung, and are you a Chinese?